# "invalid ELF header" using ctypes in lambda

Tags: python, c, aws-lambda, shared-libraries, ctypes

Try to call c function from python using `ctypes` in lambda and get:

```
Test Event Name
sdcd

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "./convolution.so: invalid ELF header",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 702, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 843, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/main.py\", line 6, in <module>\n    convolution = ctypes.CDLL(so_file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py\", line 373, in __init__\n    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
[ERROR] OSError: ./convolution.so: invalid ELF header
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    convolution = ctypes.CDLL(so_file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)[ERROR] OSError: ./convolution.so: invalid ELF header
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    convolution = ctypes.CDLL(so_file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
END RequestId: a172c0c3-4107-47a0-bccb-0b2105c152db
REPORT RequestId: a172c0c3-4107-47a0-bccb-0b2105c152db  Duration: 1457.34 ms    Billed Duration: 1458 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 11 MB

Request ID
a172c0c3-4107-47a0-bccb-0b2105c152db
```

Locally it works correctly. How I got this error:

1. create C function
2. create *.so file from this function
3. using ctypes check that locally this code works correctly
4. put *.py and *.so files into zip
5. upload archive to the lambda function
6. got error above

This is my main.py file:

```
import ctypes

so_file = "./convolution.so"

convolution = ctypes.CDLL(so_file)
convolution.convolution.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)

def createResp(status_code, body):
    return {
        'statusCode': status_code,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': json.dumps({
            'data': body
        }),
        "isBase64Encoded": False
    }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    a = [1, 3, 6, 7]
    b = [2, 4, 5, 6]

    if len(a) != len(b):
        return createResp(400, "arrays should have the same size")
    if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
        return createResp(400, "inpuit arrays should contains at least of 1 element")

    inputArraySize = len(a)
    resSize = inputArraySize*2-1
    a_arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(a))(*a)
    b_arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(b))(*b)
    tmp = convolution.convolution(a_arr, b_arr, inputArraySize)
    res = tmp[0:resSize]
    return createResp(200, res)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `print(sys.platform, os.uname())`? How did you build *convolution.so*?

Answer (score 2):

- *.so files are architecture dependent.
- This happens when you build on one architecture and then attempt to use the same built addon on a different architecture.

Ex: When you build this on your machine (x86_64), but lambda is not same aarch with your machine's aarch.

Comment: Alternatively, the `.so` might not be an ELF-format shared object at all.  For example, the same error could be expected if it were a Windows DLL, a macOS .dylib, or a static library.